# How to convert TTML (Timed Text Markup Language) tick to seconds

Tags: c#, ttml

Does anyone know how I can convert a TTML-tick to a second? For example, how do I convert "1281697500" to ~2min7sec?

Comment: 2min7sec are 127 seconds. Seems the value represents 128.1697500 seconds

Comment: It looks like it might be arbitrary based on the parameters defined in the TTML. Have a look at https://www.w3.org/TR/ttaf1-dfxp/#parameter-attribute-tickRate

Comment: TimeSpan.FromTicks( int64.Parse( ttmlValue ) );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a `ttp:tickRate` parameter on the root `tt` element, which defines the number of ticks per second. It's 1 if not specified. So if you have a TTML time expression with a tick metric like "1281697500t" then remove the `t` from the end and divide the number by the value of `ttp:tickRate` to get the value in seconds.

Note that use of ticks is only intended when working in a media timebase.

Link to `ttp:tickRate`: https://www.w3.org/TR/ttml1/#parameter-attribute-tickRate

Link to TTML Time Expression syntax: https://www.w3.org/TR/ttml1/#timing-value-timeExpression